# iOS, cubemap, compass and DeviceMotion attitude

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I need to display an OpenGL cubemap (360deg panoramic image used as a texture on a cube) 'aligned' with the North on an iPhone.

0) The panoramic image is split into six images, applied onto the faces of the cube as a texture.

1) Since the 'front' face of the cubemap does not point towards North, I rotate the look-at matrix by theta degrees (found manually). This way when the GL view is displayed it shows the face containing the North view.

2) I rotate the OpenGL map using the `attitude` from `CMDeviceMotion` of a `CMMotionManager`. The view moves correctly. However, it is not yet 'aligned' with the North.

So far everything is fine. I need only to align the front face with North and then rotate it according to the phone motion data.

3) So I access the `heading` (compass heading) from a CLLocationManager. I read just one `heading` (the first update I receive) and use this value in step 1 when building the look-at matrix.

After step 3, the OpenGL view is aligned with the surrounding environment. The view is kept (more or less) aligned at step 2, by the CMMotionManager. If I launch the app facing South, the 'back' face of the cube is shown: it is aligned.

However, sometimes the first compass reading is not very accurate. Furthermore, its accuracy improves with the user moving the phone. The idea is to continuously modify the rotation applied to the look-at matrix by keeping into account the continuous readings of the compass heading.

So I have implemented also step 4.

4) Instead of using only the first reading of the `heading`, I keep reading updates from the `CLLocationManager` and use them to continuously align the look-at matrix, which is not rotate by the angle theta (found manually at step 1) and by the angle returned by the compass service.

After step 4 nothing works: the view is fixed in a position and moving the phone does not change the view. The cube is rotated with the phone, meaning that I see always the same face of the cube.

From my point of view (but I am clearly wrong) by first rotating the look-at matrix to align with North and then applying the rotation computed by "DeviceMotion attitude" nothing should change with respect to step 3.

Which step of my reasoning is wrong?